# Multiple Tiles ItemClickCommand issue for Grail

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have follow grial grid to enable the itemClickCommand.

below is the source code DashboardMultipleTilesPage.xaml:

```
<grial:GridView
WidthRequest="320"
Margin="0"
Padding="10"
ColumnSpacing="10"
RowSpacing="10"
ItemsSource="{ Binding Items }"
ItemClickCommand="{ Binding ItemCommand }"
ItemTemplate="{ StaticResource Selector }"
ColumnCount="2"/>
```

and below is from DashboardMultipleTilesViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Input;
using UXDivers.Grial;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace QlikApps
{
  public class DashboardMultipleTilesViewModel :ObservableObject
  {
     private readonly Command _itemCommand;
     public ICommand ItemCommand => _itemCommand;

     public DashboardMultipleTilesViewModel(): base(listenCultureChanges: true)
     {
     _itemCommand = new Command<DashboardMultipleTilesPage>(ItemAction);
      LoadData();
     }

     public ObservableCollection<DashboardMultipleTileItemData> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<DashboardMultipleTileItemData>();


     protected override void OnCultureChanged(CultureInfo culture)
     {
       LoadData();
     }

     private void LoadData()
     {
       Items.Clear();

       JsonHelper.Instance.LoadViewModel(this, source:"NavigationDashboards.json");
}

private void ItemAction(DashboardMultipleTilesPage items)
{
  Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Hello", 
    items.Title, "OK");

  string id = items.id; 
}
 }
 }
```

1. ItemAction(DashboardMultipletilesPage item) not fire at all?
2. How to access data which currently point to the grid?

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve

```
public ICommand ItemCommand {get; set;}
```

And

```
ItemCommand = new Command<DashboardMultipleTilesPage>(ItemAction);
```

### Update:

Make sure you have set the `BindingContext` in your `ContentPage`.

Comment: can you please explain it, this 2 line i already added in above.

Comment: yes, already replace. The action still the same, never execution.

Comment: Share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: your email please !

Comment: You share it on github .

Comment: i use google drive : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GGJGPPr214W6t5ghyV4LmvLHMlScedN0?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you set the `BindingContext`?

Comment: This has been fixed. Thanks.